# How to deploy SandBox solution with images on the Server?

Tags: sandbox-solution, solution-deployment

How can I deploy SandBox Solution from Visual Studio with images on the Server ?

When I trying to deploy it, I am getting the following errors.

1). The Project Item "Images" cannot be deployed through a Package in a Sandboxed Solution.

2). The deployment type "TemplateFile" of file "myImage.jpg" in Project Item "Images" is not compatible with a Package in a Sandboxed Solution.

Please help me to deploy it.

Answer (score 3):

You can't deploy anything to any mapped folders in Sandboxed solutions.

A Sandboxed solution cannot place physical files in the LAYOUTS virtual directory - it's just one of their limitations.

What you'll need to do is to add your images to a Module SPI folder in Visual Studio, and have the Solution deploy the module (and the files contained within) to a Document Library in the target site collection.